# How to convert raw sql to laravel fluent query builder

Tags: laravel

hello every one please i need help how would I go about this select using Laravel's  query builder? I am aware I can use a raw sql query but I would like to avoid that. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
SELECT SUM(COST) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(STOCK_ID)*PRICE COST
        FROM STOCK ST INNER JOIN PRODUCT PDT ON PDT.PROD_ID=ST.PROD_ID  
            WHERE PROD_NAME='PENCIL'  LIMIT 6  GROUP BY STOCK_ID) TB
```

The reason why i avoid the raw sql is because when i try it like this

```
 private function totalprice( $product_id)
   {
  $selltotal = 
     DB::raw("SELECT SUM(sell_rate)
      FROM
          (SELECT COUNT(stock_id) * stock_rate 
          FROM tbl_stock AS st
           INNER JOIN tbl_product  AS pdt ON pdt.product_id = st.produck_id
           WHERE produck_name = 'product_id'
           LIMIT 6)
        GROUP BY stock_id");
     return $selltotal;
     }
```

This is the error i get

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(sell_rate)
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(stock_id) * stock_rate ' at line 1 (SQL: insert into `tbl_sell` (`category_id`, `brand_id`, `product_id`, `buyer_id`, `sell_quantity`, `sell_total_price`, `sell_date`, `added_by`, `entry_time`) values (3, 5, 6, 3, 2, SELECT SUM(sell_rate)
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(stock_id) * stock_rate 
FROM tbl_stock AS st
INNER JOIN tbl_product AS pdt ON pdt.product_id = st.produck_id
WHERE produck_name = 'product_id'
LIMIT 6)
GROUP BY stock_id, 2017-08-11, 0, 2017-08-11 07:34:11))
```

please i will be very greatfull if i get a solution to my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try something? If not, read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries ; almost all SQL key-words are methods in the Query Builder

Answer (score 2):

hello i succeded in doing it myself. It may help some one someday

```
private function totalprice( $product_id)
   {
  $selltotal = DB::table('tbl_stock')
     ->select(array(DB::raw('count(stock_id)*stock_rate')))
     ->where('tbl_stock.product_id', $product_id)
     ->join('tbl_product','tbl_stock.product_id','=', 'tbl_product.product_id')
     ->groupby('stock_id')
     ->sum('stock_rate');
     return $selltotal;
     }
```